# Crashing of a compiled program in C

Tags: c

I have a program that is intended to copy 10 integers from one array to another.It is compiling without any error. It goes as follows:-

```
/* Program to copy a string from one array to another array and print the second array */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX 10
void main()
{
    int s[MAX]; // Original array
    int c[MAX]; // Array which contains the copied contents of s[MAX]
    int i;
    printf("Enter the string of 10 characters");
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)  // Storing elements in the original array
    {
        scanf("%d",s[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)  /*Copying the elements from the original array into the duplicate array*/
    {
        c[i]=s[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++) //Printing the duplicate array
    {
        printf("%d",c[i]);
    }
}
```

Its not even printing the original array. Let alone the duplicate array, which is the second half of the program.

Comment: what do you mean by "crashing"? any report?

Comment: The return type of `main()` should be `int`.  If you weren't getting compilation warnings, you need to turn on more warnings, or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `scanf("%d",s[i]);` should read `scanf("%d",&s[i]);`

Comment: Because the function takes variable number of arguments of a variety of types. Some compilers are unable to do the correct checking.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot about `&` in `scanf`. The code should be: `scanf("%d",&s[i]);`. Why? You simply give to the function the address of variable which value should be changed. Without pointers it the function wouldn't be able to change the value.

Example:

```
int function1(int a) {
    a = 10;
}

int function2(int* a) {
    *a = 20;
}

(...)
int a = 5;
function1(a);
printf("%d\n", a); /* a is still 5 */
function2(&a);
printf("%d\n", a); /* a is now 20 */
```

Comment: Your `function2` example is C++, in C it would be `void function2(int *a) { *a = 20; }`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Typo. I wanted to use a pointer - not a reference. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `&` operator during `scanf`

```
scanf("%d",&s[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `scanf` expects a pointer to an integer as a parameter. Since `s[i]` returns the value of an integer at index i in the array s instead of a pointer to it, `scanf` tries to store the scanned value to an invalid memory location causing the program to crash.

Use `&s[i]` instead to provide `scanf` a pointer.